# creating border like msg pop in css html

Tags: css, popup, border

Hey I want to make border like below in the picture which is marked red.
Could you check my code and help me? Here's the link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gumaeyg/).

Or a code-snippet

```css
.msg {
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
 <h1>
  This Promise you 
 </h1>
 <p align="justify">
  this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph 
  this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph 
 </p>
</div>
```

[image: border marked in the red]

Answer (score 3):

rotated element. positioned absolutely.

```css
.msg {
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.pointer{
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-left-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: -11px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
 <h1>
  This Promise you 
 </h1>
 <p align="justify">
  this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph 
  this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph 
 </p>
 <span class='pointer'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code-snippet:

```css
.msg {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
#triangle {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 54%, rgba(252, 253, 255, 0) 55%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
  <span id="triangle"></span>
  <h1>
    This Promise you 
  </h1>
  <p align="justify">
    this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this
    is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this
    is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph this is a little bit paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4su9L344/)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @HarisKhan If this answer solved your problem, remember to accept the answer and feel free to upvote it.